# R: cambiar el orden de las columnas ggplot

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe:

```
                plant_taxa  Abundance   plant.family
                Desconocida 4   10  ZNA
                Datura stramonium   14  Solanaceae
                Solanum nigrum  9   Solanaceae
                Verbascum sinuatum  9   Scrophulariaceae
                Galium verum    22  Rubiaceae
                Rubia peregrina 33  Rubiaceae
                Crataegus monogyna  1   Rosaceae
                Potentilla sp   5   Rosaceae
                Reseda lutea    5   Resedaceae
                Portulaca oleraceae 6   Portulacaceae
                Rumex pulcher   11  Polygonaceae
                Avena sterilis  5   Poaceae
                Avenula bromoides   2   Poaceae
                Brachypodium phoenicoides   8   Poaceae
                Brachypodium retusum    18  Poaceae
                Bromus sp   26  Poaceae
                Cynodon dactylon    16  Poaceae
                Dactylis glomerata  10  Poaceae
                Festuca sp  3   Poaceae
                Hordeum matritense  11  Poaceae
                Hordeum vulgare 5   Poaceae
                Lolium perenne  17  Poaceae
                Milium vernale  16  Poaceae
                Phalaris minor  6   Poaceae
                Poaceae 6   Poaceae
                Stipa parviflora    6   Poaceae
                Zea mays    4   Poaceae
                Plantago sp 2   Plantaginaceae
                Fumaria parviflora  10  Papaveraceae
                Papaver rhoeas  26  Papaveraceae
                Odontites luteus    5   Orobanchaceae
                Jasminum fruticans  7   Oleaceae
                Malva sylvestris    13  Malvaceae
                Asphodelus aestivus 2   Liliaceae
                Marrubium vulgare   9   Lamiaceae
                Phlomis lychnitis   5   Lamiaceae
                Salvia verbenaca    2   Lamiaceae
                Teucrium botrys 5   Lamiaceae
                Teucrium capitatum  9   Lamiaceae
                Teucrium chamaedrys 5   Lamiaceae
                Teucrium pseudochamaepitys  5   Lamiaceae
                Thymus vulgaris 5   Lamiaceae
                Hypericum pubescens 2   Hypericaceae
                Erodium cicutarium  14  Geraniaceae
                Geranium sp 8   Geraniaceae
                Quercus coccifera   13  Fagaceae
                Quercus ilex    5   Fagaceae
                Astragalus incanus  5   Fabaceae
                Lotus corniculatus  6   Fabaceae
                Medicago orbicularis    2   Fabaceae
                Medicago sp 3   Fabaceae
                Melilotus sp    1   Fabaceae
                Trifolium campestre 3   Fabaceae
                Trifolium tomentosum    1   Fabaceae
                Vicia sp    17  Fabaceae
                Cyperus longus  2   Cyperaceae
                Cucumis melo    12  Cucurbitaceae
                Convolvulus arvensis    41  Convolvulaceae
                Centranthus calcitrapae 18  Caprifoliaceae
                Desconocida 5   4   Brassicaceae
                Descurainia sophia  7   Brassicaceae
                Diplotaxis erucoides    32  Brassicaceae
                Diplotaxis sp   8   Brassicaceae
                Diplotaxis virgata  3   Brassicaceae
                Eruca vesicaria 7   Brassicaceae
                Hirschfeldia incana 14  Brassicaceae
                Lepidium draba  16  Brassicaceae
                Sisymbrium runcinatum   8   Brassicaceae
                Anchusa undulata    12  Boraginaceae
                Echium vulgare  13  Boraginaceae
                Lithospermum arvense    6   Boraginaceae
                Anacyclus clavatus  10  Asteraceae
                Andryala arenaria   3   Asteraceae
                Artemisia herba alba    6   Asteraceae
                Asteriscus aquaticus    5   Asteraceae
                Carduus bourgeanus  33  Asteraceae
                Centaurea melitensis    7   Asteraceae
                Cirsium arvense 8   Asteraceae
                Conyza bonariensis  19  Asteraceae
                Conyza canadensis   20  Asteraceae
                Dittrichia viscosa  1   Asteraceae
                Helichrysum stoechas    5   Asteraceae
                Klasea pinnatifida  1   Asteraceae
                Lactuca serriola    23  Asteraceae
                Leontodon sp    24  Asteraceae
                Picris echioides    33  Asteraceae
                Senecio jacobaea    3   Asteraceae
                Silybum marianum    18  Asteraceae
                Sonchus oleraceus   8   Asteraceae
                Staehelina dubia    7   Asteraceae
                Taraxacum officinale    9   Asteraceae
                Tragopogon sp   4   Asteraceae
                Xanthium strumarium 1   Asteraceae
                Aphyllanthes monspeliensis  2   Asparagaceae
                Asparagus acutifolius   15  Asparagaceae
                Aristolochia pistolochia    13  Aristolochiaceae
                Anthriscus caucalis 15  Apiaceae
                Daucus sp   13  Apiaceae
                Eryngium campestre  7   Apiaceae
                Scandix pecten veneris  9   Apiaceae
                Thapsia villosa 7   Apiaceae
                Torilis nodosa  5   Apiaceae
                Allium sativum  3   Amaryllidaceae
                Amaranthus sp   23  Amaranthaceae
                Bassia scoparia 3   Amaranthaceae
                Chenopodium album   21  Amaranthaceae
```

El cual he hecho un ggplot usando el siguiente código:

```
       pl<-ggplot(data=taxa_virus, aes(x=plant_taxa, y=Abundance,fill=plant.family))


       pl + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
         scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))+ 
         theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -60, hjust = 0))
```

Esto me ha generado un gráfico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado ordenar previamente el dataframe en cuestión antes de hacer el ggplot y no se me ordena con el orden que yo quiero (de manera alfabética la columna plant.family), pero aunque se ordene en el dataframe no se ordena en el gráfico, ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el orden de las barras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente, lo que te falta es ordenar las etiquetas del eje x (`plant_taxa`) en función de otro factor que es `plant.family`. Lo más sencillo y óptimo es usar el paquete `forcats` y la función `fct_reorder()`:

```
library(forcats)

ggplot(data=taxa_virus,
       aes(x=fct_reorder(plant_taxa, plant.family),
           y=Abundance, fill=plant.family)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))+ 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -60, hjust = 0))
```

---

Y el resultado algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona correctamente Patricio, muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta